# DELETE FROM Table WHERE 'RANK' > 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, conditional-statements, rank, sql-delete

I am new to the `RANK` and `CTE` queries.  The following is my query:

```
SELECT 
    *
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY name, Product ORDER BY Date desc) AS 'RANK'
FROM 
    Config 
WHERE 
    Name 
    IN
    (SELECT 
        name
    FROM 
        Config
    GROUP BY 
        Name
        ,Product
        ,Amount
        ,Date 
    HAVING 
        COUNT(name) >1) 
        AND
        Product 
        IN 
        (SELECT 
            Product
        FROM 
            Config
        GROUP BY 
            Name
            ,Product
            ,Amount
            ,Date
        HAVING 
             COUNT(name) >1)
```

The following are sample results and satisfy the conditions:

```
ID|name|Product|Amount|Date      |RANK|
---------------------------------------
1 |a   |0000   |1     |2015-01-01| 1  |
2 |a   |0000   |1     |2015-01-01| 2  |
3 |a   |1111   |0     |2015-01-01| 1  |
4 |a   |1111   |0     |2015-01-01| 2  |
5 |b   |2222   |1     |2015-01-01| 1  |
6 |b   |2222   |1     |2015-01-01| 2  |
7 |b   |3333   |0     |2015-01-01| 1  |
8 |b   |3333   |0     |2015-01-01| 2  |
```

What is the best way to `DELETE` the records that satisfy `RANK > 1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the looks of it, you want to delete duplicate entries for `Name` and `Product` leaving the newest one. You can simplify your query with this:

```
SELECT
    *,
    RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name, Product ORDER BY [Date] DESC)
FROM Config
```

You can then put it in a CTE and execute the `DELETE`.

```
CREATE TABLE Config(
    ID      INT,
    Name    VARCHAR(10),
    Product VARCHAR(10),
    Amount  INT,
    [Date]  DATE
)
INSERT INTO Config VALUES
(1, 'a', '0000', 1, '2015-01-01'),
(2, 'a', '0000', 1, '2015-01-01'),
(3, 'a', '1111', 0, '2015-01-01'),
(4, 'a', '1111', 0, '2015-01-01'),
(5, 'b', '2222', 1, '2015-01-01'),
(6, 'b', '2222', 1, '2015-01-01'),
(7, 'b', '3333', 0, '2015-01-01'),
(8, 'b', '3333', 0, '2015-01-01');

;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT
        *,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name, Product ORDER BY [Date] DESC)
    FROM Config
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1

SELECT * FROM Config
```

Comment: HAHA!! you just helped me a little bit ago on another question.  Found somehere to apply your logic from the last answer.  Ill upvote in a min

Comment: Do I need to `DROP` the `CTE` or does it dropped automatically when it leaves scope?

Comment: No need to `DROP` the `CTE`. Fore more info, read here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx#feedback. It's a great feature to learn!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CTE:

```
with todelete as (<your query here>)
delete from todelete
    where [rank] = 1;
```

Comment: Do I need to `DROP` the `CTE` or does it dropped automatically when it leaves scope?

Comment: A CTE is defined only for the statement where it is used.  It is a lot like a subquery.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a simpler way to return the result set as you wish (if you don't want to user Row_nimber() and CTE for this :) )

you want to get the most recent date by Name and product wise.

```
select c1.Name,c1.Product,c1.Amount,max(c1.Date) as Date from Config c1
group by c1.Name,c1.Product,c1.Amount
```

another way is to use CROSS APPLY,you can sort out,most recent date using that also

Thank you