# SQL DELETE - Only keep last n records in group (delete old records in group)

Tags: sql, postgresql

[Edit] : this answer helped [DELETE FROM Table WHERE 'RANK' > 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28162587/delete-from-table-where-rank-1)

I have a table which keeps track of some entity's status history (tb_status)

DDL

```
CREATE TABLE table_aa (
    id varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    -- other columns
    CONSTRAINT table_aa_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE table_ab (
    id           int4 NOT NULL,
    ref_entity_a varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    -- other columns
    CONSTRAINT table_ab_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id, ref_entity_a),
    CONSTRAINT fk_entity_a   FOREIGN KEY (ref_entity_a) REFERENCES table_aa(id)
);

CREATE TABLE tb_status (
    status_id        int8         NOT NULL,
    ref_entity_aa    varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    ref_entity_ab    int4         NOT NULL,
    insert_timestamp timestamptz  NOT NULL,
    status           varchar(255)     NULL, -- this is an enumeration
    -- other columns
    CONSTRAINT estatus_pkey PRIMARY KEY (ref_entity_aa, ref_entity_ab, status_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_entity_aa FOREIGN KEY (ref_entity_aa)                REFERENCES table_aa(id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_entity_ab FOREIGN KEY (ref_entity_aa, ref_entity_ab) REFERENCES table_ab(ref_entity_a,id)
);
```

here is an example

| status_id | ref_entity_aa | ref_entity_ab | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "a" | 1 | OK |
| 1 | "a" | 2 | OK |
| 1 | "b" | 1 | OK |
| 1 | "b" | 2 | OK |
| 2 | "a" | 1 | OK |
| 2 | "a" | 2 | OK |
| 2 | "b" | 1 | OK |
| 2 | "b" | 2 | ERROR |

I want to keep the last n records per primary key per status

so if n was 1 after the delete the table should look like this

| status_id | ref_entity_aa | ref_entity_ab | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "b" | 2 | OK |
| 2 | "a" | 1 | OK |
| 2 | "a" | 2 | OK |
| 2 | "b" | 1 | OK |
| 2 | "b" | 2 | ERROR |

```
select ref_entity_aa, ref_entity_ab, status, count(*)
from tb_status
group by ref_entity_aa, ref_entity_ab, status
;
```

This group by query returns the number of rows for each group

In the example this would be

| ref_entity_aa | ref_entity_ab | status | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "a" | 1 | OK | 2 |
| "a" | 2 | OK | 2 |
| "b" | 1 | OK | 2 |
| "b" | 2 | OK | 1 |
| "b" | 2 | ERROR | 1 |

After the delete query executes the group by query should return

| ref_entity_aa | ref_entity_ab | status | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "a" | 1 | OK | 1 |
| "a" | 2 | OK | 1 |
| "b" | 1 | OK | 1 |
| "b" | 2 | OK | 1 |
| "b" | 2 | ERROR | 1 |

The goal is to delete old records (i.e. records that have lowest value of status_id ) so that this group by query returns a count <= n

I was able to come up with this query

```
delete from tb_status as ts
where (ts.ref_entity_aa || ts.ref_entity_ab || ts.status_id) in ( -- the same constructed_id
    select ranked_query.constructed_id
    from (
        select (ts.ref_entity_aa || ts.ref_entity_ab || ts.status_id) as constructed_id,
               rank() over (partition by ts.ref_entity_aa, ts.ref_entity_ab, ts.status order by ts.status_id desc) as ranking
        from tb_status as ts
    ) as ranked_query
    where ranked_query.ranking > :numberOfRecordsToKeep -- the n in the question
);
```

Comment: Just so I am following, after the old record is deleted, the records that have a count of 2 will go down to 1? (In this case) but you want this to be done for any value for "n" you specify? 
Could you provide an example of your desired output?

Comment: The input example is the first table in my post. The desired output for n = 1 would be the second table. The query should delete all records that have the same (ref_entity_aa, ref_entity_ab, status) and only keep the last n, which in the the example is 1. The last table in my post simply shows a group by query before the delete

Comment: I'm looking at your SQL code at the top, there is a primary key for this table? what does that look like? I may need to use it to isolate what records to remove.

Comment: This is the primary key
CONSTRAINT estatus_pkey PRIMARY KEY (ref_entity_aa, ref_entity_ab, status_id)

Comment: What is the criteria to select the rows to be deleted : delete all the rows with the same `status_id` except the one with the most recent `insert_timestamp` value ?

Comment: Delete All the rows that have the same (ref_entity_aa, ref_entity_ab, status) and only keep the last n ones, last is defined either by the row's status_id or most recent insert_timestamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a rank() window function to determine which record is older (ordered descending). Then I use a subquery to isolate the primary key that identifies the record to be deleted.
This array of primary keys can be used in a WHERE clause to delete the records based on the primary key defined in the subquery.

```
  IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#TEMP') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #TEMP
    
    CREATE TABLE #TEMP (
        PrimKey             INT
        ,status_id          INT
        ,ref_entity_aa      NVARCHAR(10)
        ,ref_entity_ab      INT
        ,[status]           NVARCHAR(10)
    );
    
    INSERT INTO #TEMP (PrimKey,status_id,ref_entity_aa,ref_entity_ab,[status])
    VALUES (1000,1,'a',1,'OK')
        ,(1001,1,'a',2,'OK')
        ,(1002,1,'b',1,'OK')
        ,(1003,1,'b',2,'OK')
        ,(1004,2,'a',1,'OK')
        ,(1005,2,'a',2,'OK')
        ,(1006,2,'b',1,'OK')
        ,(1007,2,'b',2,'ERROR')
    
    SELECT * FROM #TEMP
    
    DELETE #TEMP WHERE Primkey NOT IN (
    SELECT Primkey 
    FROM(
    SELECT PrimKey
        ,status_id
        ,RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY ref_entity_aa,ref_entity_ab,[status] ORDER BY status_id DESC) [rank]
        ,ref_entity_aa
        ,ref_entity_ab
        ,[status]
    FROM #TEMP
    )A
    WHERE [rank] <= 1 --'N'
    )
    
    SELECT * FROM #TEMP
```

Let me know if this works!

OUTPUT BEFORE AND AFTER DELETE:

[image]

Or use this solution if you do not have a primary key. You can calculate one with your composite key columns and do the same idea as above. Just keep in mind the numerical datatypes will need to be converted to nvarchar() when there are NVARCHAR columns involved.

```
    SELECT --Before Delete
        CAST(T.[status_id] AS NVARCHAR(1))+T.ref_entity_aa+CAST(T.ref_entity_ab AS NVARCHAR(1))+T.[status]
        ,* FROM #TEMP T
    
    DELETE #TEMP WHERE CAST([status_id] AS NVARCHAR(1))+ref_entity_aa+CAST(ref_entity_ab AS NVARCHAR(1))+[status] NOT IN (
    SELECT CAST([status_id] AS NVARCHAR(1))+ref_entity_aa+CAST(ref_entity_ab AS NVARCHAR(1))+[status] 
    FROM(
    SELECT status_id
        ,RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY ref_entity_aa,ref_entity_ab,[status] ORDER BY status_id DESC) [rank]
        ,ref_entity_aa
        ,ref_entity_ab
        ,[status]
    FROM #TEMP
    )A
    WHERE [rank] <= 1 --'N'
    )
    
SELECT --After Delete
    CAST([status_id] AS NVARCHAR(1))+ref_entity_aa+CAST(ref_entity_ab AS NVARCHAR(1))+[status]
    ,T.ref_entity_aa
    ,T.ref_entity_ab
    ,T.[status]
FROM #TEMP t
```

OUTPUT WITH CONCATENATED KEY:(BEFORE AND AFTER)
[image]

Comment: In my case the primary key is a composite primary key, so the primary key is made of 3 columns `status` + `ref_entity_aa` + `ref_entity_ab`, I also thought of this solution where I created a query to get a table listing all (status + ref_entity_aa + ref_entity_ab) to be deleted, but I don't know how to connect that to a delete statement

Comment: I edited the answer, the bottom shows that you can concatenate the composite key columns together and do a similar idea as the primary key.